# Change Google App Engine default service runtime

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

So, I was trying to learn how to use GAE, so I used an app template from Github to make a test app.

That worked fine, but now when I want to start working on my real app...

I get this error after running `gcloud app deploy`:

`ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Service [default] uses unsupported Python 2.5 runtime. Please use [runtime: python27] instead.`

The earlier app must have used Python 27, but I want to use Python 3.

However, I cannot find a way to change the runtime for the default service.

Is there any way to do this, and if not, what should I do about it?

Answer (score 2):

To run Python3 app, use the following in your app.yaml file:

```
runtime: python37
```

More info on running Python 3 on App Engine Standard is here:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime